# Ubuntu 16.10 reboots instead of shutting down

Tags: shutdown

I'm using a Sandybridge desktop with Ubuntu 16.10.  When I try to shut down the computer (GUI or command line) it restarts after a few seconds.  It only does this when the machine has been on for a few hours.  If the machine is shut down within about 30 mins to an hour from start up it shuts down without problems.  My wake-on-lan settings are set to off.  I've looked online for months for a solution and have tried many (messing with bluetooth settings, changing usb ports, grub editing, etc.) Does anyone else have a similar problem? Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Have same problem on my system (including initial 1/2 hour period without problems), originally under windows 7 (no software fixes worked), but then same thing just occurred using Ubuntu 17.04. Would suggest a hardware problem.